# HTML UI question - can I have a checkbox inside an INPUT type=text box?

Tags: html, user-interface

I'm replacing a winforms screen with an html interface, which needs to run in IE7/8/9 & Firefox.

Currently on one of our screens we have a funky input control that looks like this:
[image: Funky winforms control]

The user can enter a value in one of three ways:

1. the user can just type into the box
2. the user can select an item from the dropdown
3. the user can tick the ‘Unopened’ checkbox, which effectively chooses a known item we call ‘Unopened’

There’s also a search button ‘…’ but that’s another control which is easy to implement.

I want to rebuild this using html and am wondering how to replace the Unopened function, as (a) and (b) are easy enough. I’m thinking I’ll just put a separate Unopened checkbox beneath the INPUT box instead of inside it, because that would be simpler. But if there's a way to keep it looking like it does now I’d probably prefer that. Is that possible?

UPDATE:

Secondary question: if I do put the checkbox inside the INPUT box using CSS am I just bringing upon myself a lot of pain with quirky little usability or layout problems or is this something that's not too unusual or hard to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it in a separate div and then position it with CSS to look like it's inside of the input field:

```
#checkbox {
position: relative;
top: -10px;
}
```

or whatever values you need...

Regarding your second question: Nope. It's not actually "inside" the box, it just appears that way. All the functionality will still be there. =)

http://jsfiddle.net/BdBTy/ is a quick example of how this works.

Comment: ok, now I know I can do this, any thoughts on whether I _should_? e.g. am I just asking for problems from a layout or usability perspective?

Comment: Oh, didn't see this comment before I edited... Layout-wise, this is actually very clean. All the functionality is still there, but the elements are just aligned so that they look prettier. And unlike margins and padding and nested whatevers, simple alignment is supported in all browsers.

As to whether you should, this is the cleanest way to get this to look like it is now. Layout-wise, the box inside the field looks kind of weird to me, but if that's what people are used to, go for it?

Comment: Thanks, that example is very useful. I played and thought a bit more and think another option is to have a link beneath the INPUT box that lets the user choose the option, which will fill in the INPUT with the appropriate known item. e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/BdBTy/17/
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

place the check right below the textbox in html

in css for the checkbox put

```
margin-top:-25px;
```

(or whatever exact number you need)